# get parent property from a child element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope persons = [{"id":123, "name": "james",
    "score": [{
      "mark": 60,
      "grade": D
    }]
}]
```

I have 2 ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons">
{{person.name}}
<span ng-repeat="scoreObj in person.score">
<p ng-click="something(person.id)"></p> <!-- won't work -->
{{person.id}} // work
</span>
</div>
```

I tried to get person.id in child element, it won't work, any idea?

Comment: It is working, I have checked this code - https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/qcvgbkfy/

Comment: It should. Here's the plnkr to prove it. http://plnkr.co/edit/rPfMhFvdYGtewb3WQulG?p=preview

Comment: Problem with `json` 1. `D`should be wrap inside `"`(qoutes) 2. add `.`(dot) between `$scope` & `persons`

Comment: Question should be closed - no problem exists here.

Answer (score 0):

It works, your json should be,

```
 $scope.persons = [{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "james",
    "score": [{
      "mark": 60,
      "grade": 'D'
    }]
  }]
```

**DEMO**

```js
var testApp= angular.module('test',[])
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.persons = [{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "james",
    "score": [{
      "mark": 60,
      "grade": 'D'
    }]
  }]



})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="testCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
      {{person.name}}
      <span ng-repeat="scoreObj in person.score">
           {{person.id}}  
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```